# OnMouseEnter / Exit repeating instead of only once

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to toggle the size of my sprite when the mouse enters and leaves my GameObject.

Trying basically to give it an "onHover" effect, since if I use the OnMouseOver it gets repeated calls.

What is happening is my GameObject is flickering, constantly printing the Entering and Exiting, and when my mouse is clicking it - it sometimes doesn't register the clicks.

It's as if the localScale change is somehow activating and deactivating it, causing the OnMouse's to retrigger?

I'll add that my GameObject has a BoxCollider2d and a Rigibody2D.

So my question is, how can I have a "mouseOver" effect by calling OnMouseEnter and OnMouseExit only once?

```cs
    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Debug.Log("MOUSE CLICKED!");
            RaycastHit raycastHit;

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit))
            {

                Debug.Log("RAYCAST HIT!");
                transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.1F, 0, 0);
                //GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;

            }
        }
    }

    public void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        Debug.Log("MOUSE ENTEREd!");
        transform.localScale += new Vector3(2f, 2f, 2f);
    }

    public void OnMouseOver()
    {
        //Debug.Log("MOUSE OVER!");
        //transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.1F, 0, 0);
    }

    public void OnMouseExit()
    {
        Debug.Log("MOUSE EXIT!");
        transform.localScale -= new Vector3(2f, 2f, 2f);
    }
```

Found this question from 2017:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1396456/enlarge-gameobject-when-i-mouse-over-the-specific.html

Comment: Tested this and can not reproduce the issue. (All I changed was using `transform.localScale *= 2f;` and `transform.localScale /= 2f;`): see [gif](https://imgur.com/dcdmEJD). Note however that your `Physics.Raycast` will never be able to hit a `BoxCollider2D` .. it is only used by the `Physics2D` engine ... both are completely separated engines.

Comment: Perhaps more details about my GameObject's parent can help reproduce. 
https://imgur.com/a/hQ6PCNY
I'm trying to narrow down the problem now